# How do I integrate handsontable with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handsontable

I would like to build a Spreadsheet App with ruby on rails. I tried http://handsontable.com/index.html for the front end, and it works fine. But how do I integrate this with rails? Does anyone have an idea how to model the ActiveRecord Models? Rows & Columns seems a little bit to unefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could use object data binding in Handsontable and then every row in the database is a row in the table. Using `onChange` callback you can save only changed records to the database.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_handsontable . 
Its a gem which wrapping handsontable .

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

> **In the view**

```
<div id="products"></div>
<script>
    var data = <%=@products%>;
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var container = document.getElementById('products');
    var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
      data: <%=@products%>,
      rowHeaders: false,
      colHeaders: ['ID', 'Name'],
      columns: [
          {data: 'id'},
          {data: 'name'}
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

> **In the controller**

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
    @products = @products.to_json.html_safe
  end
```

Hope